# pthread_create fails with ENOMEM on low free memory scenario

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a SH4 board, here are the specs...

```
uname -a
Linux LINUX7109 2.6.23.17_stm23_A18B-HMP_7109-STSDK #1 PREEMPT Fri Aug 6 16:08:19 ART 2010
sh4 unknown
```

and suppose I have eaten pretty much all the memory, and have only 9 MB left.

```
free
 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         48072      42276       5796          0        172       3264
-/+ buffers/cache:      38840       9232
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Now, when I try to launch a single thread with default stack size (8 MB)
the pthread_create fails with ENOMEM. If I strace my test code, I can see that the function that is failing is mmap:

```
old_mmap(NULL, 8388608, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC,                       
MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

However, when I set the stack size to a lower value using ulimit -s:

```
ulimit -s 7500
```

I can now launch 10 threads. Each thread does not allocate anything, so it 
is only consuming the minimum overhead (aprox. 8 kb per thread, right?).

So, my question is:

Knowing that mmap doesnt actually consume the memory, 
Why is pthread_create() (or mmap) failing when memory available is below 
the thread stack size ?

Answer (score 6):

The VM setting `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` (aka. `sysctl vm.overcommit_memory`) controls whether Linux is willing to hand out more address space than the combined RAM+swap of the machine.  (Of course, if you actually try to *access* that much memory, something will crash.  Try a search on "linux oom-killer"...)

The default for this setting is 0.  I am going to speculate that someone set it to something else on your system.

Comment: `vm/overcommit` is in zero, but I think it is somewhat related.

Comment: Yeah, this setting turns out to be more involved than I remembered...  Apparently "0" means "overcommit somewhat", "1" means "overcommit a lot", and "2" means "overcommit very little".  Or something like that.  I think the details may have changed from kernel version to kernel version...

Answer (score 3):

Under glibc, the default stack size for threads is 2-10 **megabytes** (often 8). You should use `pthread_attr_setstacksize` and call `pthread_create` with the resulting attributes object to request a thread with a smaller stack.

Comment: That is not what I am asking, I do know I can lower the stack, but that doesn't change the fact that I can not create another thread when the free mem is below the thread stack size.

Comment: Your method of measuring "free memory" is wrong. Look at the lines `CommitLimit` (total available) and `Commit_AS` (amount used) in `/proc/meminfo`.

Comment: My measuring method might be wrong. But `CommitLimit` isn't quite correct either. From `proc.txt`: "This limit is only adhered to
if strict overcommit accounting is enabled (mode 2 in 'vm.overcommit_memory')." and I have overcommit_memory in zero. Anyway thanks for the hint, seems I have to dig deep into the kernel mm to find my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`mmap` consume *address space*.

Pointers have to uniquely identify a piece of "memory" (including mmap file) in memory.

32-bit pointer can only address 2/3GB memory (32bit = 2^32 = 4GB. But some address space is reserved by kernel). This *address space* is limited.

All threads in the process share the same address space, but different process have separate  address spaces.

Comment: Indeed there is a limit in the amount of threads you can start because of address space being finite; this is not the case, however. Remember I can't start even ONE SINGLE thread. Clearly, it has enough address space (8 MB) for that.

Comment: @Ezequiel Garcia - Are you sure about this? I'm not sure of the implementation details, but it's possible that the relevant code is preferentially selecting certain address ranges that happen to be in use and will never consider the range that is free.

Comment: @Ezequiel García, try `cat /proc/<pid>/maps`, check the memory map.

Answer (score 0):

This is the operating system's only chance to fail the operation gracefully. If the implementation allows this operation to succeed, it could run out of memory during an operation that it cannot return a failure code for, such as the stack growing. The operating system prefers to let an operation fail gracefully than risk having to kill a completely innocent process.

Comment: Can you support this answer? I would like to know at least where in kernel sources can I look.